# which format of meta data is correct? link vs meta?

Tags: metadata, meta, schema.org

which one of these format is correct?

```
  <meta itemprop="thumbnailurl" content="/design/glogo.jpg" />
  <meta itemprop="sameas" content="http://examle.com" />
  <meta itemprop="image" content="/design/glogo.jpg" />
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://127.0.0.1/" />
```

or

```
  <link itemprop="thumbnailurl" content="/design/glogo.jpg" />
  <link itemprop="sameas" content="http://examle.com" />
  <link itemprop="image" content="/design/glogo.jpg" />
  <link property="og:url" content="http://127.0.0.1/" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value is an URI, use `link`.

But note that using the `content` attribute on `link` is only allowed in RDFa. You probably want to use the `href` attribute instead:

```html
<link itemprop="thumbnailurl" href="/design/glogo.jpg" />
<link itemprop="sameas" href="http://examle.com" />
<link itemprop="image" href="/design/glogo.jpg" />
<link property="og:url" href="http://127.0.0.1/" />
```